# adding authorship markup to products

Tags: microdata, bigcommerce

Hi I am looking to put authorship markup to my flowers products as all are made in house by designer florist. Any  ideas how I would implement that to a product. I would also like to mention that the site is using the BigCommerce engine.

[Flower Delivery Store](http://www.flowerstation.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

You could manually add a link to the author within the product description.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the markup into your Bigcommerce product template. You will want to mark up more data than just the author - the item & other details - as well.

Comment: By the way, it is now recommendation that you do not add authorship markup to product pages. Here is a post I wrote with further details. http://www.convergent7.com/seo/google-authorship-ecommerce/